# Parsing JSON when multiple arrays returned in Objective C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, parsing

I am trying to parse JSOn returned from the following link:

https://icansolvecouk1.fatcow.com/prco303/loginjson.php?nickname=maggie&password=maggie

which is:

```
[{"sent":"2013-05-12 09:32:14","sender":"1","recipient":"1","message":"Hey hey hey"},{"sent":"2013-05-12 16:39:02","sender":"2","recipient":"1","message":"Another message"}]
```

Using the following code in obj-c:

```
NSDictionary *user = [result JSON];
NSLog(@"NSDictionary returned: %@",user);
NSArray* arrayOfReturnedItems = [user objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"Array returned: %@",[arrayOfReturnedItems objectAtIndex:0]);
```

NSDictionary successfully stores the JSON value but errors occur later on. I am very new to Obj-C and JSON so any help is appreciated. I checked on jsonlint.com which says it is valid but I believe the reason for the errors I am getting is that I am effectively pulling back two arrays (from that URL) but not parsing it correctly. I have access to the server serving the JSON so perhaps I need to make a change there?

Spent half the day searching this site for help before I went ahead and asked so hopefully I'll get a result!

Thanks

error from xcode:

2013-05-12 23:37:20.096 SecureComms[27240:1307] -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8957e30
2013-05-12 23:37:20.097 SecureComms[27240:1307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8957e30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c98012 0x10d5e7e 0x1d234bd 0x1c87bbc 0x1c8794e 0x47dc 0x4399 0xbd8cf8 0xb4075a 0xb0e453 0xb0e164 0xb9aa31 0x49fc53f 0x4a0e014 0x49ff2e8 0x49ff450 0x91758e72 0x91740d2a)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: "errors occur later on" - this isn't much to go on. Create a test case that demonstrates the error - a mostly self-contained short piece of code that results in erroneous output, and state what output would be correct.

Comment: And the obligatory resources: http://sscce.org/, http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Apologies @millimoose. Have now added the error.

Comment: You should spend less time searching SO, and more time troubleshooting your own code. A simple log of user would tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
NSDictionary *user = [result JSON];
```

Should be:

```
NSArray *users = [result JSON];
```

Then you need to process each of (or one of) the dictionaries in the array.

Next, the `message` you're trying to extract is just a string (`NSString`), but you're code says its an array so you'll have problems there too.

You may find it useful to log the class of items to check what you think things are:

```
NSLog(@"Class or user:%@", NSStringFromClass(user));
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try now.

Answer (score 1):

A basic thing to know about JSON syntax :

- "[" refers to an **array** so we fetch the result to an **NSArray** :

  NSArray *arr= [result JSON];
- "{" refers to an **object** so we have to fetch the result to a **NSDictionary** :

  NSDictionary *dict = [result JSON];

Comment: If someone doesn't know this then I think they have never looked at JSON in their life...

Comment: @borrrden he said he is new to Obj-C so I thought it might be a useful hint ;)

Comment: Sure, it is helpful to list to corresponding classes but "A basic thing to know about JSON syntax" is something OP should already know.  Not knowing it, to me, shows a clear lack of effort into understanding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See here for help on [JSON parsing in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5):

```
 NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://icansolvecouk1.fatcow.com/prco303/loginjson.php?nickname=maggie&password=maggie"]]];
```